# Can't use tempurl with put method to upload

Tags: upload, put, openstack, openstack-swift

I have installed keystone and swift and had proxy-server.conf configured.
I can generate a temp url to download a object without any promblem..
But when I use the same way(I did changed the method into "PUT") to generate a temp url to upload a object I got error 401...The log said can't find authentication head...

I had tried all the way that I can think of to solve the problem but I got no luck:<

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that was a silly problem caused by system date between two servers are not sync...